# How can I use some package after other some other packages loaded?

Tags: use-package, lsp-mode, server, load, eval-after-load

I am trying to start `dap-mode` in my golang project. I already have `lsp-mode` config set.

for example:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :hook
  ((go-mode . lsp-deferred)
   (rust-mode . lsp-deferred)
  )
)
```

What I want is let `dap-mode` in `use-package` block, but only load the configs when it is `go-mode`.

I have wrote

```
(use-package dap-mode
  :if (member major-mode '(go-mode))
  :custom
  (dap-auto-configure-mode t)
  (dap-auto-configure-features
   '(sessions locals breakpoints expressions tooltip))

  :config
  (require 'dap-go)
  )
```

Then I have the question that, I am using emacs server and client. So if I first in my golang project, `dap-mode` has loaded, then when I in my rust project, even I don't want `dap-mode`, it is still loaded.

So actually it is some question of emacs server-client and `use-package` mode. How can I make the mode in `use-package` load in special type mode and unload in other modes without restart emacs server?

Answer (score 1):

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode (require 'dap-mode))
```

or

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'lsp-mode '(require 'dap-mode))
```

`C-h f with-eval-after-load` says:

> **`with-eval-after-load`** is a Lisp macro in `subr.el`.
>
> `(with-eval-after-load FILE &rest BODY)`
>
> Execute `BODY` after `FILE` is loaded.
>
> `FILE` is normally a feature name, but it can also be a file name,
> in case that file does not provide any feature.  See `eval-after-load`
> for more details about the different forms of FILE and their semantics.

You can add the other code you want after the `(require 'lsp-mode)`. You can put any code you like there: the Customize code you want, for options such as `dap-auto-configure-mode`, additional `require`s, and so on.